# external content type but connect to outlook is disabled

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, bcs, external-contenttype

We are unabel to enable the "Connect to outlook" ribbon button for our external list.

The external list is based on a external content type which uses a simple Web service.

The browser based UI works just great as expected but we are unable to get the "Connect to Outlook" ribbon button to becoem enabled.

We have installed all the necessary client side installs, and the connect to outlook button works fine for regualr lists.

We have mapped it to a outlook type "Contact" within SharePoint designer and mapped the single requried field of "LastName".

Unfortunately it still will not enable, has anyone had this problem or no a fix please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of IE, it most likely won't display. Go to the browsers "gear" in the top right hand corner, click and select "Compatibility View Settings" - click add and then close and refresh, that should do the trick.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as Bruce and I tried adding the site to  "Compatibility View" but it didn't solve the issue. Any other ideas?